# How to calculate the Cache Tag size from associativity and distance between aliasing sets?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Could anyone help me and give some hints about calculating the Cache Tag size with being given the following data:

1. Associativity of cache memory, in ways = 4
2. Size of cache memory = 512kB
3. Size of each line = 128 bytes
4. Minimal distance between lines of each subset = 16kB

I have found the following formula:

```
Stag = log2(Smemory*A/Scache)
```

where:

- Stag — size of cache tag, in bits
- Smemory — cacheable range of operating memory, in bytes
- Scache — size of cache memory, in bytes
- A — associativity of cache memory, in ways.

However, I'm not given  Smemory. Is there any possible way to calculate it using the given data?

Answer (score -1):

You have to make two assumptions here. First is an assumption about the address width, this is why your formula is asking for Smemory. Second is an assumption on how many bytes is one word and whether you have word-addressability or byte-addressability. Let me show you an example. Let us assume a 32bit address and byte-addressability. Then, you will have:

> ```
> # of index bits = log2(512K / 4) = 17
> # of tag bits = 32 - 17 = 15
> ```

using your formula that would be

> log2((2^32)*4/512K) = 15

If you have only word addressability with 32-bit words, then you get:

> ```
> # of index bits = log2(512K / 4) = 17
> # of tag bits = 32 - 17 - log2(4) = 13
> ```

and you have to adjust your formula to get the same result:

> log2((2^32)*4/(512K*4)) = 13

and your formula should look like:

> Stag = log2(Smemory*A/(Scache * Sword)),

where:

Sword is word size, in bytes

Comment: Word-addressability would mean fewer bits in the offset-within-line part of the address, not in the tag.  We're given the cache size and line size in bytes, not number of addressable units, so you shouldn't be multiplying `512K * 4`. I think it all cancels out since nothing involves words anywhere.  The interesting part of this question is that we're *not* given Smemory, instead given some other things like 16kB distance between "subsets", which may be sufficient.  Not sure, haven't tried to work it out, but I'm pretty sure this answer isn't correct. :/